# How to convert numeric string value to integer in android java?

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
 public void display(View view) {
    EditText edC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edC);
    TextView tvD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    try {
        String creditsS = edC.getText().toString();
        int credits = Integer.valueOf(creditsS);
        tvD.setText(credits);   
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        tvD.setText("Couldn't parse.");
    }
}
```

and when I run the program and click on the button, the app crashes. I also tried with

```
int credits = Integer.parseInt(creditsS)
```

doesn't work. Where's the problem?

Btw, I cannot print the stacktrace because the logcat continues displaying errors like an infinite loop.
Thanks. :)

Comment: What error do you get when it crashes?  Are you absolutely sure that the the EditText has only an int?  Is it possible that you've set tvD to only accept Strings, to which you are setting an int?  Really have no idea with no error messages/stack traces.

Comment: post the stacktrace, what error message are you gettin ...

Comment: it lacks sufficient information, such as exception, value of creditsS ...

Answer (score 4):

The app crashes because of this line:

```
tvD.setText(credits);
```

The problem is that you call `setText()` with an `int` as the argument. The method is defined to accept `int`s, so the compiler does not complain, but these `int`s are expected to be ids of *string resources*. If you call `setText()` with any random `int`, the app tries to find a *string resource* with that id, and crashes with a `Resources$NotFoundException` while doing that.

Just change that line to the following:

```
tvD.setText("" + credits);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not posted the `StackTrace`, so solving your problem might get tricky here. 
You are getting an unhanded exception as explained by @FD_ in his answer.
As a good precautionary measure, you should `trim()` all your strings before passing them thorough any `String related Operation/Conversion`. 
You should edit your code like this:

```
public void display(View view) {
EditText edC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edC);
TextView tvD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
try {
    String creditsS = edC.getText().toString().trim();
    int credits = Integer.parseInt(creditsS);
    tvD.setText(""+credits);   
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    tvD.setText("Couldn't parse.");
    nfe.printStackTrace();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: He already is catching NumberFormatExceptions ;)

Comment: While the app won`t crash anymore with that code, I`d rather fight the cause than the effect - see my answer ;)

Comment: PS: Hey, you copied my code

Comment: Yes, but more appropriately the app will produce a nice and reasonable StackTrace that will enable him to trace the cause of crash.

Comment: Actually i copied the code from the question, i saw your answer later when i posted mine.